# Grouping and decorating groups of parameters in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm writing a Jenkins pipeline job with quite a few parameters and I'm looking for a way to **visually** group them together so they will be easier to understand -rather than have them all just thrown in there. I'll settle for anything that at least hints a the fact that these parameters are related to each other. Could be a header, could be boxes. Is there any plugin that will help me **decorate** my inputs this way?

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

So, after much searching the web I finally found a plugin that does the trick. The [Parameter Separator Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameter-separator). The wiki page doesn't say how to make it work in a pipeline, but after some trial and error this is how I got it to work. I hope this is useful to others.

```
String sectionHeaderStyle = '''
    color: white;
    background: green;
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif !important;
    padding: 5px;
    text-align: center;
'''

String separatorStyle = '''
    border: 0;
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc;
    background: #999;
'''

properties([
    parameters([
        [
            $class: 'ParameterSeparatorDefinition',
            name: 'FOO_HEADER',
            sectionHeader: 'Foo Parameters',
            separatorStyle: separatorStyle,
            sectionHeaderStyle: sectionHeaderStyle
        ],
        string(
            name: 'FOO 1'
        ),
        string(
            name: 'FOO 2'
        ),
        string(
            name: 'FOO 3'
        ),
        [
            $class: 'ParameterSeparatorDefinition',
            name: 'BAR_HEADER',
            sectionHeader: 'Bar Parameters',
            separatorStyle: separatorStyle,
            sectionHeaderStyle: sectionHeaderStyle
        ],
        string(
            name: 'BAR 1'
        ),
        string(
            name: 'BAR 2'
        ),
        string(
            name: 'BAR 3'
        )
    ])
])
```

This is the result:
[image]

**Edit:**

I tested this with Jenkins 2.61, Pipeline Plugin 2.5 and the Parameter Separator Plugin 1.0

Comment: What would be the syntax for the Multibranch Pipeline?  There, I use "parameters{ string( ... ) }" instead. Thanks.

Comment: What is jenkins war you were using for this solution to work

Comment: @kusumat I just edited the answer to mention the versions of Jenkins and the Jenkins plugins I used.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo I believe from your snippet that your question is about the syntax for a declarative pipeline. I'm not sure. I found `@Symbol('separator')` in the repo for the Parameter Separator Plugin [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameter-separator-plugin/blob/52c52c0245ba37bcca5f63b693cad4188610220b/src/main/java/jenkins/plugins/parameter_separator/ParameterSeparatorDefinition.java#L26) but If I try `parameters {separator(name: 'foo')}` I get `Invalid parameter type "separator"`. I think you should create an issue in the Parameter Separator repo and ask the author.

Comment: @RaúlSalinas-Monteagudo I just found an issue related to this [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameter-separator-plugin/pull/8) from the 28th Aug 2018. You should try [v1.1](https://github.com/jenkinsci/parameter-separator-plugin/releases/tag/parameter-separator-1.1) although I could not find it in my Jenkins Console, so try a manual installation.

Answer (score 6):

for dsl you can specify:

```
String sectionHeaderStyleCss = ' color: white; background: green; font-family: Roboto, sans-serif !important; padding: 5px; text-align: center; '

String separatorStyleCss = ' border: 0; border-bottom: 1px dashed #ccc; background: #999; '

pipelineJob("Foo-job") {
    description("FOO with separators")

    parameters {
        parameterSeparatorDefinition {
            name('FOO_1')
            separatorStyle(separatorStyleCss)
            sectionHeader('FOO_1')
            sectionHeaderStyle(sectionHeaderStyleCss)
        }
```

Don't make the silly mistake of using the name `sectionHeaderStyle` as per example in your dsl as that will conflict with the constructor!

which you will obviously spot when you see the error:
`No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: []`

Comment: Thanks @MSillence - **parameterSeparatorDefinition** does not appear to be on the Jenkins DSL API site: https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/  However it is mentioned in this Jenkins JIRA: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-53623